# Изменить размер окна Window после отпускания кнопки мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как можно изменять размер окна при помощи кнопки мыши не динамически (т.е. сразу при перетаскивании), а только после ее отпускания?

Нужно что-то наподобие свойства `ShowsPreview` у элемента `GridSplitter`. Похожего для `Window` не нашел.

Comment: Вам хочется странного, приложения на системе должны выглядеть и вести себя однообразно. Но можно, если постараться. Сделайте кастомную non-client area, обрабатывайте изменение размеров окна самостоятельно.

Comment: @VladD, нужно для того чтоб не видеть тормозов отрисовки содержимого окна. Походу надо менять настройки содержимого.

Comment: Ну, можно, грубой силе ничего противостоять не может. Но лучше всё же пофиксить остальной код, чтобы перерисовывалось быстро.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, подписаться на изменение размеров окна, и устанавливать размер контента вручную, только когда окно «успокоится».

Самое короткое решение получается с Rx extensions (установите System.Reactive [через nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/)):

```
<Window x:Class="CustomNC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="ClientArea">
        <Grid Name="ContentHolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- тут ваш контент -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

и code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Observable.FromEventPattern<SizeChangedEventArgs>(ClientArea, nameof(SizeChanged))
                  .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3))
                  .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                  .Subscribe(args => { ContentHolder.Width = ClientArea.ActualWidth;
                                       ContentHolder.Height = ClientArea.ActualHeight; });
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

---

То же самое легко получить с более прозаическим кодом, без Rx. В XAML подпишемся на `SizeChanged`:

```
<Grid Name="ClientArea" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
    <Grid Name="ContentHolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <!-- тут ваш контент -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

и в code-behind:

```
Task currentWaitTask = null;
async void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var waitTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
    currentWaitTask = waitTask;
    await waitTask;
    if (currentWaitTask != waitTask)
        return;
    currentWaitTask = null;
    ContentHolder.Width = ClientArea.ActualWidth;
    ContentHolder.Height = ClientArea.ActualHeight;
}
```

---

Ещё одна вариация для любителей неувядающей классики, с таймером и без TPL:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += (o, args) =>
        {
            ContentHolder.Width = ClientArea.ActualWidth;
            ContentHolder.Height = ClientArea.ActualHeight;
            timer.Stop();
        };
    }

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3) };
    void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Все работает, использовал 2 вариант.

Comment: @S.Kost: Ну вот и хорошо.

Comment: да. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @S.Kost: Пожалуйста! Добавил ещё один вариант.