# Как в WPF (xaml) записывать значения slider во viewmodel только по окончательному его изменению?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В разметке есть slider который c помощью Binding SomeProp записывает данные во ViewModel.

В самой ViewModel в Сеттере (set) сразу записываю данные в базу данных, понятное дело что таким образом при передвижении ползунка начинается запись всех значений, а мне нужно что бы записало только то значение на котором мы остановились. LossFocus только если кликнуть уже в другом месте, что не очень приемлемо.

Как поступить?

Xaml

```
<Slider Grid.Row="7"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Height="98"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Maximum="1"
        Minimum="0"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        TickFrequency="0.0000001"
        TickPlacement="TopLeft"
        Value="{Binding No1TransShift}" />
```

ViewModel

```
public string No2TransShift
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue<string>(No2TransShiftProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(No2TransShiftProperty, value);
                //Sent To DataBase
            }
        }
        public static readonly PropertyData No2TransShiftProperty = 
                      RegisterProperty("No2TransShift", typeof(string), null);
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить задержку `Value="{Binding No1TransShift, Delay=...}"`

Comment: А как вы собираетесь отличать ситуацию, при которой юзер закончил перемещение слайдера, от ситуации, когда он только приостановился?

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575983/10105

Comment: ну что то по типу когда левую кнопку мыши отпустил, тогда и записать, что то в таком роде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данную проблему можно решить при помощи механизма `Behavior` из пакета **[Expression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/)** и использования `UpdateSourceTrigger` равного `Explicit`. `Explicit` означает, что для обновления значения в привязанном свойстве нужно вызвать метод `UpdateSource` от `BindingExpression` ручками. Его мы будем вызывать в поведении для `Slider`, в котором подпишемся на событие `DragCompleted` внутреннего элемента `Thumb` (данное событие наиболее соответствует заданному в вопросе).

Расширение для рекурсивного поиска в визуальном дереве:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public static class VisualTreeExtensions
    {
        public static T FindVisualChildByType<T>(this DependencyObject parent)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (parent == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                T typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild == null)
                {
                    foundChild = child.FindVisualChildByType<T>();
                    if (foundChild != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foundChild = typedChild;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return foundChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Поведение:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class SliderBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnSliderLoaded;
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnSliderLoaded;
        }

        private void OnSliderLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var thumb = AssociatedObject.FindVisualChildByType<Thumb>();
            thumb.DragCompleted -= OnThumbDragCompleted;
            thumb.DragCompleted += OnThumbDragCompleted;
        }

        private void OnThumbDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var bindingExpression = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(Slider.ValueProperty);
            bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

Тут нужно отметить, что по моему опыту поведения работают достаточно непредсказуемо в разных окружениях (например, внутри `TabControl`). Нужно понимать, что метод `OnAttached` может вызываться несколько раз в течение жизни элемента управления. Также как и метод `OnDetaching`, который предназначен для чистки ресурсов поведения после выгрузки элемента управления. Однако, магия: этот метод иногда не вызывается вообще, при каких условиях точно сказать не могу, но проблема подробно обсуждалась на enSO. Однако, при условии подписок только на внутренние элементы ассоциированного объекта, утечек памяти не будет, потому что почистится все и сразу, поэтому я не переопределяю метод `OnDetaching`, только слежу за тем, чтобы не происходило двойных подписок.

Разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Slider Value="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
            Maximum="1"
            Minimum="0">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:SliderBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Slider>
</Window>
```

Пример рабочий.